# Как получить URL картинки из веб в Java

Tags: java, http, url

В Хроме, при правом клике на картинке вылетает меню, где есть пункт "Получить URL картинки".

Как такое же реализовать на Java? Просто класс, который получает URL при LMB+Shift (например) в браузере на картинку.

Спасибо!

Comment: А можно поподробнее? Клик куда? На ссылку в браузере?

Comment: Клик на изображение. Потом программа загружает его на жесткий диск.
Но чтобы Java его загружала, мне нужна ссылка URL